# Looking for the name of Gaussian concentration inequality

Tags: probability-theory, concentration-of-measure

It holds for a Gaussian random variable $Y$ with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$ such that $$P(|Y|>t)\leq C\exp(-t^2/(4A)^2)$$
where $A$ and $C$ are constants.

Is there a name for this inequality?

Comment: What is the relation between constants $A$, $C$, and $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$?

Comment: I think it is similar to sub-Gaussian tail bound, if $Y$ is sub-Gaussian. If you do not give the relation between parameters, it is hard to tell whether this inequality is true or not.

Comment: that is exactely the reason why I ask for a name; I don't know the relation. I have just seen the inequality being used so I was wondering whether someone knows a name so I can find more about the requirements/conditions on $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$.

Comment: Where do you see this inequality, from a text or lecture notes?